# Is the display name for an email sender considered in spam detection?

Tags: email, spam, mail-sender

We're using SendGrid for sending transactional email in a business-to-business application xyz.com.

All emails have their sender/from display name and address set as `"XYZ <info@xyz.com>"` and so far we haven't had any spam problems.

We're aware that we can't change the email address of the sender (it must remain as an address *@xyz.com from our domain for spam reasons), but are we totally free to change the display name? For example, if a business ABC is using our application, can we safely set the sender information to `"ABC <info@xyz.com>"` so that the receiver at least sees the business name ABC which actually initiated the transactional email through our app? We're thinking that this, in combination with a "reply-to" address set to "abc@abc.com" would be a reasonable solution for a businesses using our application.

Does all this sound reasonable and "ok practice"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about email deployment, not about programming.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you know where such questions should be posted?

Comment: Hesitantly thinking http://superuser.com/ but maybe think about phrasing your question in terms of a quantifiable answer (e.g. how many per cent of deliveries would fail) instead of asking people to reveal what *their* secret spam filter does.

Comment: Also what's with the square brackets? Proper SMTP looks like Real Name <address@example.com>

Comment: Yeah SO uses the angle brackets for markup, and I couldn't quickly figure out how to escape an angle bracket. I knew I wouldn't get away with it :)

Comment: The easy escape is to use `\`<code>\`` formatting.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate that. Have updated.